# Google user login when testing local app

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication

I'm working on an app that consumes the Google Drive API. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client) states two conditions necessary for authentication to be successful:

> The user is signed-in to their Google account.
>
> The user has granted permission to your app to access their data within the requested scopes.

How can I allow the user to sign in when testing locally?

My app is currently built with the Jekyll framework, which serves locally to 127.0.0.1:4000.

Comment: In the developer console of your application, you have to configure the url for your app, in this case localhost with the port you will use. check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in some [additional documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication).

In the following function, changing `immediate` from `true` to `false` forces the app to ask for authentication. Otherwise, authentication silently fails if the user isn't logged in.

`function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}`